# Inserting row in Data extension using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, dataextensions, postman

I'm unable to add data to Data extension using API. I tried multiple times from postman, however I'm getting same error. I'm I missing something here?

```
{
    "documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
    "errorcode": 0,
    "message": "Not Authorized"
}
```

My Data extension is as follows:
[image]

Postman API call:
[image]

Headers:

[image]

Comment: what is the scope of your installed package and what is the account context and does it match the account the DE is in

Comment: @EazyE We only have one BU, and the data extension scope is set to 
Read, Write

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 401 status code in the response, which means based on [documentation for handling API errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/error-handling.html):

> The token was not found in the request, or it is invalid or expired.
>
> or
>
> Ensure that access token is passed in the request header.

So check your Postman's variable `{{access_token}}` within the current environment:

- Are you actually receiving the token?
- Are you setting it into variables correctly?
- Is the variable name correct?
- Token [expires in 20 minutes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/access-token-s2s.html), maybe just refresh the authentication request would solve the issue
- You can also try moving variable `{{access_token}}` to the "Authorisation" tab (before the "Headers" tab), where you would select the "Bearer Token" option from the dropdown